I need to compare a large pdf file with a large excel file, and spot the differences in data
I keep running into errors like this :
raise IllegalCharacterError(f"{value} cannot be used in worksheets.")
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.IllegalCharacterError: uP   j         AS       ▼        V        6  Q    H    F O   Q    x    o            6     PK      PK LnX       cannot be used in worksheets.
import pandas as pd
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import difflib
import re

# Define the PDF file path
pdf_path = "./pdf_name.pdf"
excel_path = 'excel_name.xlsx'

# Function to extract text from PDF using PyPDF2
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, "rb") as file:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(file)
        text = ""
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    return text

# Function to read entire content of Excel file as a string
def read_excel_as_string(excel_path):
    try:
        with open(excel_path, "r", encoding="latin1") as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Excel file not found.")
        return ""

# Function to clean text data
def clean_text(text):
    # Remove any characters that are not printable ASCII or illegal in Excel
    cleaned_text = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isprintable() or x.isspace() or ord(x) > 31, text))
    # Replace any problematic characters with a space
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', cleaned_text)
    return cleaned_text


# Function to find differences between two texts
def find_differences(text1, text2):
    diff = difflib.ndiff(text1.splitlines(), text2.splitlines())
    diff_data = []
    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('+'):
            diff_data.append(["", line[2:], "Added"])
        elif line.startswith('-'):
            diff_data.append([line[2:], "", "Deleted"])
        elif line.startswith(' '):
            diff_data.append([line[2:], line[2:], "Matched"])
    return diff_data

# Extract text from Excel
excel_text = read_excel_as_string(excel_path)

# Extract text from PDF
pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path)

# Clean the PDF and Excel text
pdf_text_cleaned = clean_text(pdf_text)
excel_text_cleaned = clean_text(excel_text)

# Find differences between PDF and Excel files
diff_data = find_differences(pdf_text_cleaned, excel_text_cleaned)

# Create a DataFrame to store the differences
diff_df = pd.DataFrame(diff_data, columns=["PDF", "Excel", "Status"])

# Write the DataFrame to an Excel file
diff_df.to_excel("./differences.xlsx", index=False)



Please include the full traceback.

Your issue might be coming from the way you read the Excel file which is not plain text.
Have you tried using pandas ?
Try importing all text in one string to compare with the string from the pdf.
def read_excel(excel_path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
        return '\n'.join(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Excel file not found.")
        return "" 

